# Problemas en el zoom mapa iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapa

tengo la implementación de google maps en mi app de iOs hecha en swift (Xcode), cuando ingreso al mapa el zoom no se va directo a la coordenada que establecí en el código, anexo foto y fragmento de codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var myUserLocation: CLLocation?
    var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
    var zoomLevel: Float = 5.6
    var iduser: String! = ""

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.2988906, longitude: -3.0492199, zoom: zoomLevel)
```

Comment: En dónde tienes el código? `viewDidLoad()`, `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: Hola buen dia, viewDidLoad()

Comment: Intentaste colocar el código en `viewDidAppear()`?